# registerHook to display at the top of the list

Tags: prestashop-1.6

In prestashop 1.6

I use the following code to display data in the top column`$this->registerHook ('displayTopColumn')`

The module should display first in the displayTopColumn list.

Once in a while I have to reset my module and the hook is re-register at bottom of the displayTopColumn list, and I have to go manually to `position` and move it back to the top of the list.

Is there a way to register a hook to display at the top of the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course there is.

In your module install method

```
public function install() {
    return parent::install() 
        && your hook registers 
        && $this->updateHookPosition('displayTopColumn', 0 /* DESC */, 1);
}

public function updateHookPosition($hook_name, $way, $position) {
    $id_hook = Hook::getIdByName($hook_name);

    return $this->updatePosition($id_hook, $way, $position);
}
```

Comment: Note: $way should be 0 - i.e. DESC